# save a file generated by a php script in to a directory by save dialog form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, savefiledialog, filedialog

I have a php script that generate a pdf file.
So I have an html page with jquery javascript that do an ajax call at this php script and retrieve the pdf file content.
I would that this file will be saved in a location choosed by a save file dialog.

How can I do it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: the php script retrieve some $POST variable useful for pdf generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Ajax - just do a

```
location.href = "fileURL.php";
```

(or alternatively, have the user click on a link) and if the headers are set correctly, a download dialog will present itself.

Comment: Chrome usually opens its built in pdf viewer, but there's the `Content-disposition: attachment` header.

Comment: i think it is not useful because the pdf file is generated passing some $POST variable to the php script

Comment: @michele  then create a form with the POST method, and submit it, which will then trigger the download.  You can't use Ajax for this, it's impossible to start a file download that way

Comment: I can't create a form...how can I do? At the moment I have returned via $ajax the pdf content and I would visualize it or save somewhere.